# std::time() and its dependence on daylight saving

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a requirement to lock a user, if 3 consecutive login attempts are failed within 15 minutes. I am going to check with the following formula, if third login attempt fails.

```
    if (first_login_attemp_time + 900 <= std::time(nullptr))
    {
        lockuser();
    }
```

If the first login attempt fails, I set first_login_attemp_time as given below

```
first_login_attemp_time = std::time(nullptr)
```

Will this code work if daylight saving time change occurs in the 15 minutes window?
Should I consider something else for day light saving?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/gmtime gives UTC, no daylight savings madness

Comment: @Mat does that mean std::time(nullptr) is OK to use?

Comment: @Maanu No, it means that it isn't.

Comment: Check [steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) if you want to measure interval between times without such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`std::time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) returns UTC time that does not follow daylight saving policies of local authorities. So about daylight savings there are no worries.

Like the cited reference article says most systems implement `std::time_t` (that `std::time` returns) as in POSIX standard. In my experience it is all systems that I know of.  So it is extremely likely to be integral value in seconds and so your `+ 900` results with its advance by 15 minutes.

However logic of your code is strange. It locks user when more than 15 minutes has passed since first attempt and that is not usually what is called "within 15 minutes".